# Jmeter version on Linux says newest version but doesn't seem to be

Tags: jmeter

I build jMeter .jmx tests on my local windows machine with jMeter 5.0 r1840935
This seems to be the latest install for windows.
I run the jmx tests from a Ubuntu machine on the command line, problem is there is a version descrepency - well at least I assumed there was as I was getting NPE errors when trying to run the .jmx from command line (works fine from Windows GUI)
When I check the version in Linux

```
jmeter --version
Copyright (c) 1998-2014 The Apache Software Foundation
Version 2.11.20151206
```

OK, but when I install again it claims that v2 is the latest version :

```
apt-get install jmeter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
jmeter is already the newest version (2.11-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into [`jmeter` package details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) none of Ubuntu distributions as of now has JMeter newer than version [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/four-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213) (which is 4+ years old by the way)

Therefore you have 2 options:

1. (Not recommended) Download [JMeter 2.11](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.zip) and create Test Plan on Windows machine using older JMeter version
2. ([Recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)) Install latest JMeter onto your Ubuntu machine.

   - Make sure that you have Java 8 installed (or higher). If not - install it by executing the following command:

     ```
     apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
     ```
   - Download JMeter 5.0 (or whatever version is available at [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

     ```
     wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.0.tgz
     ```
   - Unpack it

     ```
     tar xf apache-jmeter-5.0.tgz
     ```
   - Launch it

     ```
      apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/./jmeter.sh --version
     ```

   Assuming everything went well you should see JMeter 5.0 version as the output:

   ```
   root@4cb26685e15a:/# apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/./jmeter.sh --version
       _    ____   _    ____ _   _ _____       _ __  __ _____ _____ _____ ____
      / \  |  _ \ / \  / ___| | | | ____|     | |  \/  | ____|_   _| ____|  _ \
     / _ \ | |_) / _ \| |   | |_| |  _|    _  | | |\/| |  _|   | | |  _| | |_) |
    / ___ \|  __/ ___ \ |___|  _  | |___  | |_| | |  | | |___  | | | |___|  _ <
   /_/   \_\_| /_/   \_\____|_| |_|_____|  \___/|_|  |_|_____| |_| |_____|_| \_\ 5.0 r1840935

   Copyright (c) 1999-2018 The Apache Software Foundation

   root@4cb26685e15a:/#
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just install JMeter 5.0 locally by downloading it from jmeter website:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

The version distributed with ubuntu is outdated